# Starting/Stopping single instance with CLI

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I wonder how to start/stop a ColdFusion 10 instance from terminal. If I restart the CF Server, it automatically starts the cfusion instance; other instances need to be started with CFIDE/administrator -> Enterprise Manager -> Instance Manager -> click on play-icon:

[image: CFIDE Server Manager - Instance standardwebs running after clicking on play]

How could I start my instance named "standardwebs" from command line?

Comment: I've not done multi-instance CF10 stuff, but I'd start by looking in {instance-dir}/bin and seeing if it contains any startup scripts - it does for a standard install.

Comment: @PeterBoughton you're right. I found the startup script named `coldfusion`in every {instance-dir}/bin. Thanks alot. PS: Can you make your comment an answer please?

Comment: Done... although really an accepted answer should be more fleshed out than just one sentence, but I don't have time for that at the moment, so if anyone else wants to write up something more comprehensive, go ahead...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look in `{instance-dir}/bin` and you should find a startup script for that instance.